# Android service design considerations

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem. I am working on an android application that needs to do the following:

1. It should run on the background indefinitely (not possible, but close to indefinitely) and update a notification.
2. If the notifaction is clicked the background service should switch between an active and inactive state.
3. If the service is in the active state it should read sensor input and respond to it.

Now I tried the IntentService which I found out stops after a while. So now I am switching to the normal service. However what is the best way to respond to this notification click? Should the service extend the BroadcastReceiver to respond to a broadcast sent on the notification click or should I extend the SensorEventListener because it does need to listen to the sensor events? And if I extend the SensorEventListener how should I handle the notification click event?

Answer (score 0):

When a service decides to notify about something it can create a notification in the status bar by means of `NotificationManager`.

When you tap the notification in the `NotificatonManager` you can start your `Activity`.

When this activity gets created you can bind from it to the server using `ServerConnection` so you can get and display any relevant data

Answer (score 0):

Your service can "throw" a notification as described here: [Notifitcations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

For a notification, you can set an Activity which is opened when the user taps the notification or some control in the notification.

To communicate with a service, you can apply a "client-server-connection" between an activity and a service or two services by using Bound Services: [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

According to a services lifecycle, you have to declare the states in the service when it is active or inactive. By interpreting the intent from the notification which is given to the activity, you can forward this over the binding (applied by a `Messenger`) and change your services's state from inactive to active or from active to inactive.

To sum up:

1. You define two states in your service (initial maybe "inactive").
2. When you start your application, bind the MainActivity and your background service so they can communicate (especially your Activity can tell your service something)
3. When you bind your service, this will also start its lifecycle where you directly can "throw" the notification with the "switch". Add your MainActivity to the notification as described in the API-Doc.
4. When returning from tapping the notification to your activity, define what the activity shall send to the service by using the Messenger. in your service, define a separate logic to switch the states
5. Throw a new notification to switch the state back
6. In your service, you can listen to the sensors by a SensorListener or anything else

I hope this helps you a bit - becase this is not an easy task it is a little bit extensive to post a Proof of Concept here.

Comment: Can in this case the service also run and handle click events without the main activity running?

Comment: IMHO this is not possible as a service is designed not to react on user input but for background jobs while an Activity is for user actions and gestures.